# Get list items into array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the values of a bunch of list items into an array.

This is what I'm trying at the moment:

```
var array = $('li').each(function () {
  $(this).html();
};
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var array = $('li').map(function() { return $(this).html(); }).get();
```

You can do it with `.each()`, but you have to actually build an array explicitly:

```
var array = [];
$('li').each(function() { array.push($(this).html()); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost done.

With little modification's,

```
var array =[];

$('li').each(function () {
  array.push($(this).html());
});
```

[**Have a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshbm13/fRUUd/1577/)

Answer (score 0):

## [Working Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/bypsE/)

You need to use push for adding values to your array

```
 items.push($(this).html());
```

See your code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bypsE/)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method is to use the Array prototype method `slice`, but since there's a jQuery method of the same name, probably not necessary. Some nice information to know tho.

```
var array = [].slice.call($('li')).map(function(el) {
  return $(el).html();
});
```